# How to determine cause of CPU halt

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64

I'm working on a research project that involves developing a new DVFS algorithm for Intel machines. To do this we're utilizing some of the code from the intel_pstates driver to actually determine the pstate for each individual CPU and using the wmsr function to set that value to registers (IA32_PERF_CTL).

The problem we're encountering is when we run benchmarks, the CPU will randomly halt (not kernel panic or system hang).

Is there a way we can setup a trace or another method to record the value that was trying to be written to the MSRs?